# What is Iced Web Control Panel

Tags: bluetooth

In the process of setting up my new RPi 2 B, in particular Bluetooth, after a reboot the following appeared under menu/preferences "Iced Tea Web Control Panel" and "OpenJDK Java 6 Policy Tool". I didn't ask for them, they don't appear to do anything,I've looked them up and don't understand their description; in layman's terms does anyone know what they are for and how I could get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed any applications that use Java (libre office, web browser, eclipse etc) you will have the setting tools for Java (which is what you are seeing).
To list installed things relating to Java:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i java
```

List what depends on a package:

```
apt-cache rdepends default-jre
```

For more information on a package:

```
apt-cache show default-jre
```

To remove a package:

```
apt-get purge default-jre
```

Many more options are listed in the user manual for each command:

```
man apt-get
```

Or you may want to just remove the menu items:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/ && mv openjdk* icedtea* itweb* ../
```

Answer (score 1):

"Iced"-Tea is an implementation of the Sun Java software by Free Software. Similar to a normal Java control panel.

Comment: As I said in the question, I've looked it up but the description doesn't tell me anything, I need an answer in layman's terms